# Display ads without leaving app

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I'm looking at some ad SDKs and it's difficult for me to find a way to present them without leaving the app. I've tried a handful of them but lets say AdMob for purpose of answering this question.

**Is there a way to present AdMob ads in an in-app browser once they are clicked? Or would I have to use a different SDK if I want to achieve that.**

If the answer is the latter, what well known Ad SDKs would let me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the target page in Safari and not in an in-app browser is on purpose: Safari allows to better track the users. The reason is related to the cookie handling: Safari stores cookies globally while the *UIWebView* based in app-browsers have a cookie store restricted to a single app. Therefore with in-app browsers, you cannot track users across apps.

However, there is a solution to mitigate the problem provided you have a certain control about the ads (and aren't simply taking the from a network).

An ad can consist of more than just an image with a target link. It can contain interactive elements. You can take advantage of it by creating an ad that opens an overlay when tapped. The overlay shows a web page within your app. The user can then either close it or tap a link that takes her to a further web page shown in Safari.

The standard API to implement an overlay supported by most ad SDKs is MRAID. Google Mobile Ads SDK (formerly known as AdMob SDK) supports it. The Google SDK additionally supports the AdMob SDK.

Good examples for such ads can be found on a [Google support page](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1656921?hl=en). Specifically check out "Sample Code for an expandable ad (MRAID)" and "Target window: in-app overlay window".